Reset Application Folder Access
While opening Disk Inventory X for the first time in a while, it began asking for permission to access different folders on my drive. I placed my mouse over the first "allow" button. A couple more "allow" buttons went by, then the next request placed "don't allow" in the place where "allow" was. I had just enough time to recognize that it said "Don't Allow" but not enough time to stop myself from clicking.
How do I reset these Files and Folders permissions so I can rescan? closing and re-opening the app did not prompt a rescan.
I went to System Settings, Privacy and Security, Files and Folders, But I think that's only allowing me to revoke access, and doesn't display permissions that were declined.

Do you want to find out the system name of that app to reset just it or is it OK to reset all the settings and start with a blank slate?
